# Using LVM with RAID1

Tags: linux, lvm, opensuse, software-raid

I am using SLES 15 SP3. I need to setup RAID1 with LVM using autoyast.xml

In the AutoYast guide, I found examples of how to setup:

- [LVM](https://documentation.suse.com/sle-micro/5.1/html/SLE-Micro-all/cha-configuration-installation-options.html#ay-partition-lvm)
- [RAID](https://documentation.suse.com/sle-micro/5.1/html/SLE-Micro-all/cha-configuration-installation-options.html#ay-partition-sw-raid)

They seem pretty straightforward and I even tried them and it works fine.
But I could not find any example of how to setup both of them using AutoYast.

Then I found some examples using command line

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Raid1_with_LVM_from_scratch

https://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager

so, I followed the instructions and setup LVM RAID1

```
# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/nitin-vgr1/nitin-lvr1
  LV Name                nitin-lvr1
  VG Name                nitin-vgr1
  LV UUID                kPeOlZ-1laD-faVM-o20q-wd0y-wala-N3kMNq
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time nit, 2021-11-13 17:28:19 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                49.99 GiB
  Current LE             12798
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     1024
  Block device           254:9
```

Each disk was 50 GBs (/dev/sdd and /dev/sde) , LV Size  = 49.99 GiB so that makes sense

Mirrored Volumes is also set to 2. So seems like RAID1 conf was working fine

And I was also aware of the command `yast clone_system` (this basically generates the autoyast.xml fpr running system which contains system configurations details)
but unfortunately this didn't work as excepted:

this was the output(I removed all other unnecessary stuff)

```
<partitioning t="list">
    <drive t="map">
        <device>/dev/nitin-vgr1</device>
        <partitions t="list">
            <partition t="map">
                <create t="boolean">true</create>
                <filesystem t="symbol">ext4</filesystem>
                <format t="boolean">false</format>
                <fstopt>rw,relatime</fstopt>
                <lv_name>nitin-lvr1</lv_name>
                <mount>/nit-raid</mount>
                <mountby t="symbol">device</mountby>
                <pool t="boolean">false</pool>
                <resize t="boolean">false</resize>
                <size>53678702592</size>
                <stripes t="integer">2</stripes>
                <stripesize t="integer">0</stripesize>
            </partition>
        </partitions>
        <pesize>4194304</pesize>
        <type t="symbol">CT_LVM</type>
    </drive>
    <drive t="map">
        <device>/dev/sdd</device>
        <disklabel>none</disklabel>
        <partitions t="list">
            <partition t="map">
                <create t="boolean">false</create>
                <format t="boolean">false</format>
                <lvm_group>nitin-vgr1</lvm_group>
                <resize t="boolean">false</resize>
            </partition>
        </partitions>
        <type t="symbol">CT_DISK</type>
        <use>all</use>
    </drive>
    <drive t="map">
        <device>/dev/sde</device>
        <disklabel>none</disklabel>
        <partitions t="list">
            <partition t="map">
                <create t="boolean">false</create>
                <format t="boolean">false</format>
                <lvm_group>nitin-vgr1</lvm_group>
                <resize t="boolean">false</resize>
            </partition>
        </partitions>
        <type t="symbol">CT_DISK</type>
        <use>all</use>
    </drive>
</partitioning>
```

I don't feel this is correct. There is no mention of `RAID1` here.

Can anyone please help me out here. Its been 2 days and I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this. Here are the steps to follow in [`expert-partitioner`](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book-reference/cha-expert-partitioner.html#) while installing OS.

- Create RAID1 `/dev/md0` (99.87 GIB) from `/dev/sda` (100.00 GIB) and `/dev/sdb` (100.00 GiB),
- Create partition `/dev/md0p1` (5.00 GiB) for `/boot/efi` with `vfat`
- Create partition `/dev/md0p2` (94.87 GİB) as LVM physical volume
- Create volume group `raidvg` (94.87 GiB) with `/dev/mdOp2` (94.87 GiB)
- Create LVM logical volume `/dev/raidvg/var` (54.87 GIB) on volume group raidvg for `/var` with `btrfs`
- Create LVM logical volume `/dev/raidvg/system` (40.00 GiB) on volume group `raidvg` for `/` with `btrfs`

Once system installation is over, use `yast2 system_clone` command to generate autoyast file in `/root` dir.

The rules to setup LVM with RAID1 will be in this file in `partitioning` section.